# Cannot find jquery.couch.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, docker, couchdb

I am trying to get started using couchDB. While standing up a cluster of three docker containers is easy enough using this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/gesellix/couchdb-cluster-config), I cannot create a javascript program to query the database.

All the guides I find say the required libraries live at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:15984/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js
```

and

```
http://127.0.0.1:15984/_utils/script/jquery.js
```

However, when I try to run this, I keep getting a not found response. What am I doing wrong?

**Note**:

- I know normally the port is `5984` but with my docker cluster `15984`
  is the correct choice
- Going to `localhost:15984/_utils`, `localhost:25984/_utils`, and `localhost:35984/_utils` takes me to the CouchDB interface.
- I cannot connect to the couchdb using the container's IP addresses
- I can also use `172.17.0.1` in place of localhost

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is your own computer (localhost). You are querying your own computer to get those files, meaning you must have a file server listening on port 15984, I doubt it's the case. Why don't you simply pull the libraries from a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/)? That's what they're here for.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the localhost interface. If you are trying to connect to the container if it is run with the default network configurations which is bridge, first get the container IP address by running `docker inspect {container-id/name}` and try connecting to this IP Address. It will be something like `172.17.0.2` if default docker bridge is used

Comment: @JeremyThille sadly jquery.couch.js is not on a CDN